How to avoid code duplication when testing many types against many concepts?
I want to check if a (long) list of types (in this example just char and int) fulfil a (long) list of C++20 concepts (in this example just is_foo and is_bar). I currently approach this is as follows:
#include <concepts>

template <class T>
concept is_foo = std::destructible<T>;

template <class T>
concept is_bar = std::integral<T>;

template <class... Ts>
concept all_are_foo = (is_foo<Ts> && ...);

template <class... Ts>
concept all_are_bar = (is_bar<Ts> && ...);

int main() {
  static_assert(all_are_foo<char, int>);
  static_assert(all_are_bar<char, int>);
  return 0;
};

In the above example there are two sources of code duplication:

Every basic concept is_x requires a variadic all_are_x counterpart.
For each all_are_x concept one must re-type the whole list of types.

When the number of concepts and/or the number of types grow this quickly becomes cumbersome. How can I enforce the same concepts in a shorter way? I would like to do something similar to the following pseudocode:
#include <concepts>
#include <tuple>

using type_list = std::tuple<char, int>;

template <class T>
concept is_foo = std::destructible<T>;

template <class T>
concept is_bar = std::integral<T>;

int main() {
  static_assert(is_foo<type_list...>); // pseudocode
  static_assert(is_bar<type_list...>); // pseudocode
  return 0;
};

I'm open to all sorts of solutions. The type_list doesn't have to be a std::tuple, and all template metaprogamming techniques and macros are allowed.

If you create all_are_foo_and_bar, you write the aggregate traits only once, and so, you only have one traits, so only one type_list.
